# yii2 full calendar events won't drag

Tags: yii2, fullcalendar

I am passing events from a database to the view. Using the latest calendar plugin.
However I cannot get the event to drag from one day to another.
Here is controller:

```
    public function actionAllEventsmod()
{
    $events = Events::find()->all();
    $tasks = [];
    $draggable = "fc-draggable fc-resizable";
    foreach ($events as $eve) {

        $event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();

        $house = House::getHouseAddress($eve->house_id);
        $details = $house->address_line_1 . " -- " . $house->city . " -- " . $house->comments;

        $event->id = $eve->event_id;
        $event->start = $eve->start;
        $event->end = $eve->end;
        $event->title = $eve->title;
        $event->description = $details;
        $event->className = $draggable;
        $event->editable = true;
        $event->backgroundColor = $eve->background_color;
        $tasks[] = $event;
    }

        return $this->render('all-events', [
        'events' => $tasks,
    ]);

}
```

view:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\web\JsExpression;

$JSEventClick = <<<EOF
function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    alert(calEvent.title + ' -- ' + calEvent.description);
}
EOF;

$this->registerJs($JSEventClick);
?>

<?= yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
        'events' => $events,
        'id' => 'calendar',
        'clientOptions' =>[
        'allDaySlot' => false,
        'eventLongPressDelay' => 1500,
        'selectLongPressDelay' => true,
        'hiddenDays'=> [0],
        'height' => 'auto',
            'minTime' => '08:00:00',
            'maxTime' => '20:00:00',
        'selectable' => true,
        'selectHelper' => true,
        'select' => function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        'droppable' => true,
        'draggable' => true,
        'editable' => true,
        'eventStartEditable' => true,
        'drop' => new JsExpression($JSDropEvent),
        'select' => new JsExpression($JSCode),
        'eventClick' => new JsExpression($JSEventClick),
        'eventLimit' => true,
        'eventDrop' => function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
            alert(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format());
            if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
        }),
        'eventRender' => new JsExpression($JSEventRender),
        'eventResize' => new JsExpression("
            function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                console.log(event);
            }"),
  ],
  ));
?>

<?php

$JSCode = <<<EOF
function(start, end) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    var eventData;
    if (title) {
        eventData = {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end
        };
        $('#w0').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
    }
    $('#w0').fullCalendar('unselect');
}
EOF;

$JSDropEvent = <<<EOF
function(date) {
    alert("Dropped on " + date.format());
    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
    }
}
EOF;

?>
<div class="well"> 
<pre>
Event Hover:
<?= Html::encode($JSCode); ?>

Event JSDropEvent:
<?= Html::encode($JSDropEvent); ?>  

</pre>
</div>

</div>
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: any errors in your console when you do this? Also what version of fullCalendar? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/Requirements/ - if you have 2.1 or above (which you really should) then you don't need all the jQuery draggable stuff.

Comment: latest version of full calendar

Comment: I don't know Yii, but am I right in thinking the "DragJS" will only run when the "eventDragStart" callback is triggered? It doesn't really make sense to me - "eventDragStart" is for dragging "internal" events (already on the calendar), but then you make it initialise some "external" events. What's the logic here? And can I ask you again, do you get any errors in your browser console when dragging and dropping between days? Can you start to drag, but not finish? Or not start at all?

Comment: You are right, do not need the drag.  Just trying things.  Events are not editable.  I cannot move them at all. When I hover the cursor changes to a hand, but I cannot do anything.  No console errors.

Comment: Ok. If you've got `editable:true` in the main calendar settings, then according to the docs you don't then need `eventStartEditable: true`, nor do you need `editable:true` for each individual event. I doubt you need `$draggable = "fc-draggable fc-resizable";` and `$event->className = $draggable;` either - this is internal fullCalendar stuff which it should be setting up itself. If you start messing with it, you might break something.